# bison and user classes: compiling error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to create a toy language with simple grammar using `C++`, `flex` and `bison`. I have four files: `types.hpp`, `scanner.l`, `parser.y` and `Makefile`. When I'm trying to compile, for each function inside `types.hpp` ld says that it has been already defined. I guess that problem is in the include directives. Here is what I have in the beginning of each file (I omit content of grammar because I think it's not the reason; if there will be a need, I'll publish it):

// scanner.l

```
%{
#include "parser.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
  int yylex(void);
} /* extern "C" */

char BUFFER[32768];
int POSITION;

%}

%option noyywrap
%x COMMENT
%x BYTESMODE
%x indent
%s normal
```

// parser.y

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
  int yylex(void);
  int yyparse(void);
  int yywrap() { return 1; }
} /* extern "C" */

void yyerror(const char *error) {
  cerr << error << endl;
} /* error handler */

%}

/*============================================================================*/
/* Create Bison union and stack */
/*============================================================================*/
%code requires {
#include "types.hpp"
}

%union {
  object_type* pointer;
  type_type*   type_buffer;
  none_type*   none_buffer;
  bool_type*   bool_buffer;
  int_type*    int_buffer;
  float_type*  float_buffer;
  bytes_type*  bytes_buffer;
} /* union */
```

// types.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//============================================================================//
// Declare classes
//============================================================================//
class object_type;
class none_type;
class type_type;
class bool_type;
class int_type;
class float_type;
class bytes_type;

type_type  type_function(object_type* object);
bytes_type name_function(object_type* object);
bytes_type repr_function(object_type* object);
bool_type  bool_function(object_type* object);
int_type   int_function(object_type* object);
float_type float_function(object_type* object);
bytes_type bytes_function(object_type* object);
```

// Makefile

```
caesar: scanner.l parser.y types.hpp
    clear && clear && clear
    bison -d parser.y -o parser.cpp --graph
    flex -o scanner.cpp scanner.l
    g++ -Wall -g -o $@ parser.cpp scanner.cpp -lfl
```

Where the error can be? I guess it's trivial, but since I'm novice to C++, it's pretty hard for me to find it. Thanks in advance! If there will be need, I'll post the whole code.

Here is an example of error message.

```
/home/ghostmansd/lang/types.hpp:559: multiple definition of `repr_function(object_type*)'
/tmp/ccv2zJdS.o:/home/ghostmansd/lang/types.hpp:559: first defined here
```

Repository: http://github.com/ghostmansd/caesar

Comment: parser.y and scanner.l are incomplete? try to use something like `#pragma once` in types.hpp. But when I make them complete (by just adding the %% and some dummy rules, it compiles and links ok.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What do you mean? I have defined tokens in `scanner.l` and some working rules in `parser.y`. Do you want to see the full code?

Comment: [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: @ghostmansd: Sure I want to see the full code, because I wanted to compile it.

Comment: @DimaRudnik: thanks, I've already thought about this, but adding `#ifndef TYPES_HPP`, `#define TYPES_HPP` and `#endif` to `types.hpp` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ghostmansd: nevertheless, it always looks confusing seeing a header file without guards, its asking for trouble (sooner or later)

Comment: @pbhd: here is it, I've created a repo. https://github.com/ghostmansd/caesar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have implementation in your header file, e.g.

```
type_type::~type_type(void) { /* destructor */ }
```

This needs to go to types.cpp, in types.hpp you should only have the class definition (unless you inline that stuff, but that would be the second step). This is because if types.hpp gets included more than once, you also have two implementations hanging around, which the linker does not like.

You also should not declare variables in the types.hpp.

Comment: And how can I then compile adding `types.cpp`? How will I make it work?

Comment: You have to move all the implementation stuff to types.cpp. (See also the other post about the constants) Your last line in the makefile then just includes types.cpp: `g++ -Wall -g -o $@ parser.cpp scanner.cpp types.cpp -lfl`

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'll mark this one as right, because author explained me that I shall not mix `hpp` and `cpp` files. But the first answer explains the reason of error. If I could, I've choosen two right answers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You define constants in the header file:

```
const none_type NONE_TYPE;
const bool_type BOOL_TYPE;
const int_type INT_TYPE;
const float_type FLOAT_TYPE;
const bytes_type BYTES_TYPE;
```

That cause problems during linking, because same symbols exists several times.

One way to avoid that problem:

You should only declare those as external in the header:

```
extern const none_type NONE_TYPE;
extern const bool_type BOOL_TYPE;
extern const int_type INT_TYPE;
extern const float_type FLOAT_TYPE;
extern const bytes_type BYTES_TYPE;
```

And define only in one cpp file:

```
const none_type NONE_TYPE;
const bool_type BOOL_TYPE;
const int_type INT_TYPE;
const float_type FLOAT_TYPE;
const bytes_type BYTES_TYPE;
```

And the same problems seems to occur also with function definitions of header.